# Why root user has different library version than simple user?

Tags: linux, root

I was trying to build one project with cmake but turned out that root doesn't have it (admin user had it).
After installing it on root they have now different versions. I thought that root has only more access privileges than normal user and they have same files.
Why is so?

```
admin@raspberrypi:/home/pi/profinet/p-net $ cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.0

admin@raspberrypi:/home/pi/profinet/p-net $ sudo su
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/profinet/p-net# cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.4
```

Comment: This is not a raspberry pi specific question, the answer will be the same for any Linux system. Nevertheless, this comes from differences in the PATH for different users. Probably local installation of cmake is referenced in the admin user PATH higher than a global or any other installation used by the root. Typing `which cmake` may give you some more details

Comment: How did you install your special version (V3.26.0) of cmake?

Comment: I  think you mean you installed a new version and don't understand why root is still using the old one; `which cmake` (try it as user then root) will probably shed some light on that.

Comment: `admin@raspberrypi:~ $ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
admin@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo su
root@raspberrypi:/home/admin# which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
root@raspberrypi:/home/admin# cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.4
root@raspberrypi:/home/admin# exit
exit
admin@raspberrypi:~ $ cmake --version
cmake version 3.18.4`

Pretty strange now they look the same :(